# Texture image doesn't automatically put on the right place

Tags: texturing, uv

I used to do this in Blender 2.8 and just add an image texture and it automatically goes in to place but when I downloaded 2.9 it goes like this (image below). How can I fix this? I need help thanks.

[image]

Comment: Please use punctuation in your sentences to make the text readable.

Answer (score -1):

Okay, I now know the answer my texture contains other mesh that is not there what I did was remove and them and just download the texture of that mesh alone. Thanks and sorry